# Create a new column in python dataframe based on the presence of NaN in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe with NaNs

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30, np.nan], "B": [20, np.nan, 10,np.nan]})

     A     B
0  10.0  20.0
1  20.0   NaN
2  30.0  10.0
3   NaN   NaN
```

I would like to create a new column 'C'. 
In  any row if either column 'A' or 'B' has a NaN, column 'C' will be set to 0 else 1.

I would like to get as below:

```
      A     B  C
0  10.0  20.0  1
1  20.0   NaN  0
2  30.0  10.0  1
3   NaN   NaN  0
```

I tried the below code:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row:0 if (row['A']=='NaN' or row['B']=='NaN')  else 1, axis=1)
```

I get the below df. Column C is always set to 1.

```
      A     B  C
0  10.0  20.0  1
1  20.0   NaN  1
2  30.0  10.0  1
3   NaN   NaN  1
```

Tried the below code as well:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row:0 if (row['A'].isnull() or row['B'].isnull())  else 1, axis=1)
```

getting the below error.

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `notnull` + `all`:

```
df['C'] = df.notnull().all(1).astype(int)    
df

      A     B  C
0  10.0  20.0  1
1  20.0   NaN  0
2  30.0  10.0  1
3   NaN   NaN  0
```

Comment: That works. I have more columns in my dataframe. I don't want to use all columns, but I want to check specific columns only for NaN. How do I specifiy them?

Comment: @mnr `cols = ['A', 'B', ...]; df['C'] = df[cols].notnull().all(1).astype(int)` remember to accept the answer if it helped. Thanks.